# Selecting the filter type in React Table on the UI

Tags: reactjs, react-table

I'm trying to create a stylized table that includes a dropdown for selecting the filter type, e.g. equals, not equals, greater than, less than, etc. I'm using React Table and Bootstrap. Getting the dropdown is easy enough, but I can't seem to change the *filter* value of the *column*. I created a StackBlitz to demonstrate what I mean:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-89vz1j?file=custom-filter.tsx

In particular, take a look at CustomFilter. It has the dropdown to change the filter type. In it, there's a onClick callback that for each item that would set the filter value. The problem is that I don't have a hook like *setFilter* to adjust the value and update the grid. Is there such a hook? Could such a hook be built?

EDIT: Screenshot of the dropdown in question
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the solution to this. I wrote my own plugin hook that includes a new action, `setFilterType`. That function sets the state of the column to the filter type I want. I include a reference to that function on each column. Within the filter code, I can call that function. So then the dropdown can use that function to set the filter type based on what the user chooses. See my stackblitz:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-qj2sop?file=App.tsx

Answer (score 0):

I think this function is most likely available in the table instance returned by the `useTable` hook. Its `table.setColumnFilters`.

Though thats for version 8, it might have a different name in older versions. You can just log out the return of `useTable` and have a browse.

Comment: If you're referring to setFilter and setAllFilters from the useFilters hook, those are specifically for setting the filter values, not the filter type. https://react-table-v7.tanstack.com/docs/api/useFilters